# What would make django remove a trailing slash?

Tags: python, django

I need to make sure all of my urls are ending with a slash. Most of them are adding the slash to the end of a request, but I have a few that are removing the slash if I explicitly add it to the url.

For example: http://127.0.0.1/about/testing/ will redirect to http://127.0.0.1/about/testing

I am using `'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware'` and `APPEND_SLASH=True` in my `base.py`, there are no overrides in my other settings.py.

In `urls.py` the regex that catches this request is `urlpatterns += [url(r'^.+/', nav_views.default), ]`, if I comment this line I will get a 404, but the trailing slash still gets removed.

I know there is something that is missing, what possible way could the slash be getting removed?

Answer (score 0):

I always seem to do this after coming back to the problem again later.

The issue seemed to be with my catch all regex at the end of `urls.py`

Changed it to the following:

```
urlpatterns += [url(r'^.+/$', nav_views.default), ]
```

Of course there was a lot more changes to be made for my views to render correctly, but this got the slash to stay on the end of the url.